Null check operator used on a null value in my FutureBuilder
Using a project from Github that apparently works flawlessly in the video tutorial but running it on my device gives me this error message:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<List<CameraDescription>>#ee4d1):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>> FutureBuilder:file:///Users/brbyle/StudioProjects/aug_reality/lib/main.dart:82:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _MainScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:aug_reality/main.dart:88:73)
#1      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:623:55)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5599:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5487:15)

This is an excerpt of my FutureBuilder:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            if (_isPermissionGranted)
              FutureBuilder<List<CameraDescription>>(
                future: availableCameras(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    _initCameraController(snapshot.data!);

                    return Center(child: CameraPreview(_cameraController!));
                  } else {
                    return const LinearProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              ),


i think error occurs your CameraPreview Wiget please provide this code.

The issue is not in your CameraPreview widget, it's because your _cameraController is null. You're using the bang operator there when it's null which is generating the error.

Check both _cameraController and snapshot.data are not null and initialize well before using.

Try adding the following:
FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();

